# Strongly Minkowski equivalence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, locally-convex-spaces

Assume that $(X, \{ p_i \}_{i \in I})$ is a locally convex space. $A,B \subset X$ are said to be strongly Minkowski separated iff there exists $j \in I$ and $z \in X$ such that one of the following two inequalities is satisfied:
\begin{gather}
\inf \{ p_j(a +z): a \in A \} > \sup \{ p_j(b + z): b \in B \} \\
\inf \{ p_j(b + z): b \in B \} > \sup \{ p_j(a + z): a \in A \}
\end{gather}
This definition is equivalent to the existence of $\delta > 0$ and $\lambda \in I$ such that:
\begin{equation}
p_\lambda(a - b) \geq \delta \hspace{.2cm} \forall a \in A, b \in B \hspace{2cm} [1]
\end{equation}
I can not get the prove of condition [1] implies the definition of Strongly Minkowski.

Answer (score 0):

That implication seems false.

Take any normed space $E=P\oplus \mathbb{R}e$, set $A=P \oplus (1,\infty)e$, $B=P \oplus (-\infty,-1)e$.

The condition (1) is met. However, for any seminorm $p$ and any $z$, if either one of the strong separation inequalities holds, then $A$ or $B$ is bounded for $p$.

Now, since for all $x \in A$ (resp. $B$), $\lambda >1$, $\lambda x \in A$ (resp. $B$), it follows that $p(A)$ (resp. $p(B)$) is zero, and in both cases it follows that $p=0$, a contradiction.

Comment: This equivalece appers in a proceeding of the AMS

Comment: Can you disprove my counterexample? Or did you forget an assumption somewhere (eg $A$ and $B$ subspaces of $E$, maybe)?

Comment: I think you are right. I have 2 questions,  P is a normed space? and what is the  explicit norm for the space E?

Comment: $P$ is a normed space. Take $\|(a,be)\|_E=\|a\|_P+|b|$.